# Reading BigQuery output directly into dataframe 'BigQueryReadGrpcTransport' object has no attribute 'channel'

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am trying to send a query to BigQuery from python and reading the results back directly into a dataframe.  I'm receiving this attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'BigQueryReadGrpcTransport' object has no attribute 'channel'
```

I've tried

```
client.query(sqlText).to_dataframe()
```

and

```
client.query(sqlText).result().to_dataframe()
```

and both get the same error.  If I alter the query text to specify exporting the data into GCS that works fine, so the query is working.

`client.query(sqlText).result()`

gives me

`<google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator at 0x1fe13585e80>`

so I think the query is running fine without the Export option.

I'd guess this is a dependency issue?  I've updated pandas, google-cloud-bigquery, google-cloud-bigquery-storage, fastavro, and db-dtypes but the error message hasn't changed.

Are there other dependencies I'm missing or might be out of date?  Or some other cause?

Thanks in advance

I've tried updating dependencies I'm aware of, and I expect my dataframe